# dig: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed

Tags: linux, debian, dns, webserver, resolv.conf

I tried using dig and I got the error in the title.

My /etc/resolv.conf is this

```
nameserver 67.207.67.2
nameserver 67.207.67.3

nameserver ns1.name.com
nameserver ns2.name.com
nameserver ns3.name.com
nameserver ns4.name.com
```

The first two are the default digital ocean dns, the other are for my domain registrar.

So I tried to add two cloudflare dns, and the file is this:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1

nameserver 67.207.67.2
nameserver 67.207.67.3

nameserver ns1.name.com
nameserver ns2.name.com
nameserver ns3.name.com
nameserver ns4.name.com
```

After I did, dig still didn't work.

But if I comment the *name.com nameservers, dig works:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1

nameserver 67.207.67.2
nameserver 67.207.67.3

#nameserver ns1.name.com
#nameserver ns2.name.com
#nameserver ns3.name.com
#nameserver ns4.name.com
```

The fact is that if I comment these *name.com nameservers, my site goes down after some minutes.

So how can I leave these *name.com nameservers and be able to use dig and nslookup and stuff like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, only (numeric) **IP Address**es should follow `nameserver`. 
You cannot use `ns1.name.com`, etc. 
You are making a basic mistake of configuring your `/etc/resolv.conf` wrong
by using `nameserverver ns1.name.com`. 
You have already managed to fix this by commenting them out.

Second, only 3 nameservers are allowed per `/etc/resolv.conf`. So any fourth nameserver you add will be ignored. So in your `/etc/resolv.conf`, `nameserver 67.207.67.3` will be ignored.

Quoting from the man pages ([`resolv.conf(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html)):

> `nameserver   Name server IP address`
>
>   Internet address of a name server that the resolver should query, either an IPv4 address (in dot notation), or an IPv6 address in colon (and
>   possibly dot) notation as per RFC 2373. 
>   Up to
>   **`MAXNS`**
>   (currently 3, see
>   `<resolv.h>`
>   ) name servers may be listed, one per  keyword. 
>   If there are  multiple  servers,
>   the resolver library queries them in the order listed. 
>   If no
>   **`nameserver`**
>   entries are present, the default is to use
>   the name server on the local machine.  (The algorithm used is to try a name server, and if the query times out, try the next, until  out  of
>   name servers, then repeat trying all the name servers until a maximum number of retries are made.)

Answer (score 0):

Well my problem was that `/etc/resolv.conf` had a mistake in it:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

and so i had to change it to this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Try check the contents of your `resolv.conf` file
(BTW, you need to use `sudo` to edit that file)
good luck :)

Comment: This might be true but it doesn't solve the problem described by the question. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/583741/100397) for a correct solution.